# Nest API Temperature Change - Failure

Tags: nest-api

I'm writing an app in node.js to control a Nest Thermostat and I'm having some problems.  My first attempt was to repurpose the Nest provided app (https://github.com/nestlabs/control-jquery), but when I install it, it works fine to display temp, but when I click the temp up/down buttons nothing happens.

When I detach the temperature change function from the JQuery click event, and just run the function on load, Firebase responds with "FAILURE".  Here's the error:

FIREBASE WARNING: set at /devices/thermostats/C8Wx6yQWsEhWa-k5ZWvRslx2bB6bvpId/target_temperature_f failed: failure

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Check the hvac mode of the thermostat you are adjusting. 
- You cannot set the target temperature if the hvac is in heat-cool or off mode.
- You cannot set the high range temperature or low range temperature if the hvac is not in heat-cool mode.
Check the 'away' mode.
- You cannot set the target temperature if the building is in away mode.

See the error codes documentation:
developer.nest.com/documentation/error-codes

Answer (score 0):

Did you select read AND write permissions when you created the Nest Client?

Comment: Yes.  Every permission is selected Read and Write.